# Excluding region in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to create a contour plot of a function that goes to infinity at `x=1` and `z=0` as can be seen by plotting it for `x=1`:

```
zmax = 4;
fun[x_, y_, z_, xp_, yp_] := -(3*z^3)/(2*Pi*(z^2 + (x - xp)^2 + (y - yp)^2)^(5/2));
Plot[fun[1, 1, z, 1, 1], {z, 0, zmax}]
```

[image]

The following code

```
ContourPlot[fun[x, 1, z, 1, 1], {x, -2, 3}, {z, 0, zmax}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotPoints -> 50, Frame -> True, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 10, LegendMarkerSize -> 350], Below], 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-0.5, 0}}]
```

produces a contour plot with a white area around the singularity:

[image]

The question is: how to get rid of the white area. I would like to exclude the region around point `{1,0}` from the calculations and set its colour to black (or any other). I tried adding  something like

```
Exclusions -> {{x < 1.5, x > 0.5, z < 0.5}}, ExclusionsStyle -> Black
```

but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see this right, then you don't need this. The inner white "circle" is already clipped. Therefore, the only thing you have to add is `ClippingStyle -> LightGreen` and you get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So simple! Thank you :-)